# sendto on Tru64 is returning ENOBUF

Tags: linux, unix, sockets

I am currently running an old system on Tru64 which involves lots of UDP sockets using the sendto() function.  The sockets are used in our code to send messages to/from various processes and then eventually on to a thick client app that is connected remotely.  Occasionally the socket to the thick client gets stuck, this can cause some of these messages to get built up.  My question is how can I determine the current buffer size, and how do I determine the maximum message buffer.  The code below gives a snippet of how I set up the port and use the sendto function.

```
/* need to adjust the maximum size we can send on this */
/* as it needs to be able to cope with the biggest     */
/* messages we send                                    */

lenlen = sizeof(len) ;

/* allow double for when the system is under load */
int                 lenlen, len ;
lenlen = sizeof(len) ;
len = 2 * 32000;

msg_socket = socket( AF_UNIX,SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

 result = setsockopt(msg_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char *)&len, lenlen) ;

    result = sendto( msg_socket,
                         (char *)message,
                         (int)message_len,
                         flags,
                         dest_addr,
                         addrlen);
```

Note.  We have ported this application to Linux and the problem does not seem to appear there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

UDP send buffer size is different from TCP - it just limits the size of the datagram. Quoting Stevens UNP Vol. 1:

> ...
> A UDP socket has a send buffer size (which we can change with `SO_SNDBUF` socket option, Section 7.5), but this is simply an upper limit on the maximum-sized UDP datagram that can be written to the socket. If an application writes a datagram larger than the socket send buffer size, `EMSGSIZE` is returned. Since UDP is unreliable, it does not need to keep a copy of the application's data and does not need an actual send buffer. (The application data is normally copied into a kernel buffer of some form as it passes down the protocol stack, but this copy is discarded by the datalink layer after the data is transmitted.)
>
>     UDP simply prepends 8-byte header and passes the datagram to IP. IPv4 or IPv6 prepends its header, determines the outgoing interface by performing the routing function, and then either adds the datagram to the datalink output queue (if it fits within the MTU) or fragments the datagram and adds each fragment to the datalink output queue. If a UDO application sends large datagrams (say 2,000-byte datagrams), there's a much higher probability of fragmentation than with TCP. because TCP breaks the application data into MSS-sized chunks, something that has no counterpart in UDP.
>
>     The successful return from `write` to a UDP socket tells us that either the datagram or all fragments of the datagram have been added to the datalink output queue. If there is no room on the queue for the datagram or one of its fragments, `ENOBUFS` is often returned to the application.
>
>     <sub>Unfortunately, some implementations do not return this error, giving the application no indication that the datagram was discarded without even being transmitted.</sub>

The last footnote needs attention - but it looks like Tru64 has this error code listed in the [manual page](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V51_HTML/MAN/MAN2/0097____.HTM).

The proper way of doing it though is to queue your outstanding messages in the application itself and to carefully check return values and the `errno` after each system call. This still does not guarantee delivery (since UDP receivers might drop the packets without any notice to the senders). Check the UDP packet discard counters with [`netstat -s`](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V51_HTML/MAN/MAN1/0253____.HTM) on both/all sides, see if they are growing. There is really no way around this besides switching to TCP or implementing your own timeout/ack and re-transmission logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using some sort of congestion control to avoid overloading the network. By far the easiest way to do this is to use TCP instead of UDP.

It fails less often on Linux because UDP sockets wait for space in the local network interface queue on Linux (unless you set them non-blocking). However, with any operating system, if the overfull queue is not in the local system, the packet will be dropped silently.